# Redirect user from domainone.com to domaintwo.com

Tags: apache

I am trying to physically redirect a user from domainone.com to domaintwo.com but the .htaccess code I have keeps the user on the page but loads in content from domaintwo.com into domainone.com.

I would like the user to actually be taken to domaintwo.com.

```
Redirect 301 domain.com.au domain.com
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in your .htaccess file located on domain.com.au

**Redirect 301 / http://www.domain.com**

Comment: Where do I write a .htaccess in a django project ?